# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'darknet.dll' (or one of its dependencies)

Tags: python, darknet

I am using cuda 8 and yolo4. i want to detect object using darknet. when i am calling `detect_image` method, it is showing given below error.

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'darknet.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
i am using pycharm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.environ['PATH'] = cwd + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
 ib = CDLL("darknet.dll", RTLD_GLOBAL) .         Error is showing after execute last line.